# Using getElementById to disable an Ext.Button

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have some javascript in which I need to get an Ext.Button object by its id, and then disable it.

I can do this with an Ext.form.TextField, but not with an Ext.Button object.

Even if I do it like this...

```
var coeiTextField = new Ext.Button({
    text: 'My Button'
    width:110,
    id: 'my_button',
    disabled: false,

});
```

and then do...

```
document.getElementById("my_button").disabled=true;
```

It never works.  I know my code is basically right because it works if I do it with an Ext.form.TextField - just not an Ext.Button.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use the component API, you need to call `disable` on the component, not the underlying DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `disable` method.

`coeiTextField.disable();`

If you want to query the button,

```
var button = Ext.getCmp('my_button');

button.disable();
```